# TimeZoneInfo Ambiguous one hour before needed for Romance Standard Time

Tags: c#, timezone

I am trying to control Daylight saving in a C# application instead of letting windows do it. (I won't come into the reason here).

So I have removed the checkmark "Automatically adjust clock for daylight saving" in Date and Time settings (Windows7)

I have written this small piece of code in order to demonstrate the problem that I am facing.

```
TimeZoneInfo tzi = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id);
                                                    // "Romance Standard Time"
var rule = tzi.GetAdjustmentRules()[0];

System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.ClearCachedData();
var timestampToWorkOn = DateTime.Now; 
Console.WriteLine("Timezone is: " + tzi.ToString());
Console.WriteLine("Timezone id is: " + tzi.Id);
Console.WriteLine("Timestamp right now: " + timestampToWorkOn.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"));
Console.WriteLine("Rule for change says: " + rule.DaylightTransitionEnd.TimeOfDay.ToString("HH:mm"));
Console.WriteLine("Is it dst: " + tzi.IsDaylightSavingTime(timestampToWorkOn));
Console.WriteLine("Is it ambiguous:" + tzi.IsAmbiguousTime(timestampToWorkOn));
```

As the transition from dst to normal time is supposed to happen at 3:00 I would suspect that the time from 2:00 to 3:00 would be Ambiguous.
But the result from running the code at 1:54 is:

> Timezone is: (UTC+01:00) Brussels, Copenhagen, Madrid, Paris
>   Timezone id is: Romance Standard Time
>   Timestamp right now: 2013-10-27 01:54
>   Rule for change says: 03:00
>   Is it dst: False
>   Is it ambiguous:True

I might be missing something.
I would expect dst to be true and ambiguous to be false, but it is the opposite way around.

It's hard to keep an overview but why am I seeing this behavior?

Comment: Picking the *exact* date that daylight savings time changes is no doubt part of the problem.  Throw in the "I'll do it myself" angle and the UTC+1 offset to arbitrarily add an hour to the problem.  Make the hurting stop by exclusively working in UTC.

Comment: But the goal is to control windows' time. Including dst transitions.  if I want to work in pure utc, and I want reach the goal of controlling the time transistions, I need to have me a database with all the rules for all the time zones.....and maintain it. I think I might want to take a closer look at noda time. ....

Comment: Are you trying to create Iversen Standard Time?  That's actually possible, TimeZoneInfo.CreateCustomTimeZone().  Convincing other programs to use it could well turn out to be a problem.

Comment: I am not. Basically it is because it need to control a windows embedded pc with enhanced write filer on the c drive. So nothing gets comitted to the c drive and thus each time windows boots after a transition, it thinks that it needs to adjust the time. Again and again. The end result is that the time drifts one hour each time the pc is booted. So i have to control it by myself and store the current dst status to the d: drive

Comment: I have to say, I wouldn't have guessed in a hundred years that this was the actual problem you are trying to solve.  Tinkering with TimeZoneInfo isn't ever going to get you close to a solution.  Ask at superuser.com, explain the real problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: I usually tell people to never uncheck that box, and preferably set their servers to UTC time zone.  But you say this isn't running on a server, but on an embedded device?  Please tell us exactly what version of Windows you are running.  It will matter very much. (I believe the issue you are describing is known and resolved since Windows Vista, but I don't know about on Embedded).

Answer (score 0):

You should read [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2007/06/07/exploring-windows-time-zones-with-system-timezoneinfo-josh-free.aspx), which describes in detail how the Windows registry settings are affected by the time zone selection and the "Automatically adjust..." checkbox.  It also describes how `TimeZoneInfo` uses these settings.  Specifically, it states:

> When daylight saving time is disabled for the local time zone, `TimeZoneInfo.Local` will return a TimeZoneInfo object with `TimeZoneInfo.SupportsDaylightSavingTime` set to False.  Any `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(...)` calls using this `TimeZoneInfo` instance will not take daylight saving time into account.

IMHO, there is never a good reason to clear that checkbox and disable DST.  It puts the computer's clock in an artificial reality.

If you are running code on a server, you should probably set the server's time zone to UTC.  This will keep Windows from having to update the computer's bios for the transition, and will let local timestamps from other servers all line up.

Regarding your code, realize that the result of `DateTime.Now` has `.Kind == DateTimeKind.Local`, and has no bearing on the time zone you used earlier.  You happened to be reporting the local time zone, but if you used a different one, your code would be incorrect.

When you are getting the adjustment rules, you are assuming the local time zone will have one.  Some (like Arizona) do not have any DST, so they have no adjustment rules and you get an index out of bounds exception (because of the `[0]`).

Also, just being nitpicky but,

```
// This line is self redundant.
TimeZoneInfo tzi = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id);

// It can be reduced to:
TimeZoneInfo tzi = TimeZoneInfo.Local;
```

But the real problem is that because you have the "adjust for DST" option turned off, the DateTime is not being converted to the right UTC moment in order to make the determination if it is ambiguous or not.  If you drill in to the .Net source code (decompiled or symbolsource) for `DateTime.IsAmbiguousTime()`, you will find that it uses `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime()`, which (per the earlier quote) does not take DST into account when the box is unchecked, thus making the result incorrect (essentially 1 hour off).

You should also look at the MSDN notes for [`TimeZoneInfo.IsAmbiguousTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396403.aspx), which describe how the `Kind` of the input affects the output result.